# Android Java String creation 'cheapest' way

Tags: java, android, string, memory

I have a runnable that is constantly updating a string value onscreen, there could be ten items in a list all updating their value every second. Its basically a list of stopwatches all running at the same time. The method I have below has three different ways of producing the string:

```
private void setTime() {

    long now = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000L;
    long difference = now - startTime;

    // METHOD 1
    String conc = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", difference / 3600, (difference % 3600) / 60, difference % 60);

    // METHOD 2 (not finished)
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(8);
    sb.append(difference/3600).append((difference % 3600 /60)).append(difference % 60);

    // METHOD 3
    String timeAsText = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss")
                .format(new Date(difference * 1000));        
}
```

All of them work, but after watching the memory whilst performing the same test for each method and leaving it for 10 minutes the allocation continues to rise for each.

Method 1 - Allocated memory went up about 5MB-6MB.

Method 2 - Allocated memory went up about 3MB.

Method 3 - Allocated memory went up about 6MB.

After only 10 minutes this isn't ideal, I have tried to track the memory allocation and the issue is definitely with creating the String.

How best should I do this? What method can I employ to keep memory allocation to a minimum? Even better what can I do to stop the memory constantly rising? (This is definitely a new issue by the way, taking this out stops the leak)

Comment: When `String` value keeps on changing, it is recommenced to take `StringBuilder` because it is mutable. (i.e it doesn't create new object when you change the value)
So your method 2 is good.

Comment: What happens after 20 minutes? Memory consumption grows twice?

Comment: @PragnaniKinnera That isn't going to help him here.  My bet is he wants to write it to a TextView at some point, so he'll need to buid the string.  At that point it isn't mutable.  Your advice is more correct if you're talking about appending data constantly.

Comment: Strings are immutable, so I'm voting for the `StringBuilder` solution.

Comment: @Foxinsocks it will be double yes. The string builder option grows at roughly 0.3MB a minute.

Comment: I will test the theory now however, 15 minutes to go. (Y)

Comment: @Murphybro2 If you are good enough in handling array, then you could take a character array,  because you have control over your memory

Comment: I don't really see a leak here.  I just see GC not running, probably because total memory usage isn't high enough for it to have bothered yet.  Unless you're doing something weird with the string returned, of course.  I'd go with option 1 though.  Option 3 creates a lot of temporary objects.  Option 2 is also ok, but the old C programmer in me finds  1 clearer.

Comment: @Murphybro2 and if you initiate `gc` will memory restore? I would say that it's quite hard to give some advices knowing your figures. Just because even if your app eats up 20mb of memory it could be normal behaviour in some circumstances at some devices.

Comment: Well then guys, I'll just put it down to normal behaviour! It's not a problem as such, I was just curious about if there was a better way to go about it! Thanks anyway

Comment: Whilst I've got you here, using stringbuilder how can I get the format of time, i.e. "04:33:53".. using Method 1 I used "%02d:%02d:%02d" but I don't know how to apply that to stringbuilder..?